# Intellij IDEA builds artifacts even if not needed

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Inside my project I have 2 modules.

1. core stuff
2. web (depends on core)

Web also has an artifact to create war file. When I compile simple command-line class from module 1, IDEA rebuilds artifact (it takes a lot of time due to enormous amount of libraries). In my run configuration 'Build artifacts' checkbox is not set. How can I avoid building artifacts? Idea version ultimate 11.1.

Comment: Could you provide more details of your project structure - is this a plain intellij java project, maven project etc?

Comment: A plain intellij javaa project.

Comment: Please contact JetBrains support with a sample project to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Well, I've registered another bug 1 month ago, even one more user has confirmed it yet. But no reaction since that time.

Comment: So, what is the policy on fixing bugs, how long may this take? I am not registered user...

Comment: @stiv, I've been waiting on bugs for years. They fix them if they want to. For example: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69417 and http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-27250

Comment: Thanx for your comment. If I was JetBrains, I'd focus on fixing bugs rather on adding new features. IDEA is more stable then eclipse (IMHO), but many basic functions have glitches...